# Oracle linked functions in anonymous block

Tags: oracle, recursion, plsql, anonymous

I wonder if there is a way to do something like this.

```
declare 
 function a(apar in varchar2(1000)) return number;
 function b(bpar in varchar2(1000)) return number
 as 
 begin 
--   something something something with the a() function
 end b;

 function a(apar in varchar2(1000)) return number
 as
 begin
      -- something with the b(bpar in varchar2(1000)) function
 end a;

 select f from tbl where b(f) = 1;

end
```

This is a recursion I use to check if I need to show a row from a select.
And I want to do this in anonymous block, but oracle tells me that I'm wrong:

`ORA-06550 : the b function cannot be used...`

How to overcome this ?

Comment: There is no need to specify the size of a `varchar2` formal parameter of a function(`apar in varchar2(1000)`) - it would be interpreted as an error. Moreover, even if you decided to use a constrained subtype `say subtype t_1 is varchar2(1000)` to declare a formal parameter of a function, the size would be ignored, and you could easily pass in an actual `varchar2` value that exceeds 1000 bytes (or characters, depending on `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` settings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use functions in queries, if they have been declared in an anonymous block.

You need to `CREATE` those functions, or better, but them into a package together (you also need to define them in the package header).

Comment: `or better put them into a package`. In a case of recursively dependent functions, putting them in a package is the only option. It wont be possible to compile stand-alone, recursively dependent functions due to unavailability of forward declaration. Moreover, you do not have to declare them all in a package specification, only those that have to be available for a caller. If there is no need for function `a()` to be available for a caller it might not be included in the package specification - only package body.

Comment: +1: The SQL engine needs to be able to compile the SQL statement, and thus the function must be visible to it.